# How to fix " item.item_name is null "

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a search field in my dashboard and I have get api in this api have array and in the array I have objects so how I can do it in react what logic I should apply on it .

Here is the logic I apply on it but it returns error that

This is error:

`TypeError: item.item_name is null`

and this is logic i apply on it :

```
handleChange = event => { 
    const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase();
    this.state.all_items.filter(item => {
      // console.log(item)
      return (item.item_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedFilter) !== -1)
    }); 
    this.setState({ SearchResult: event.target.value });
  };
```

and here is input field :

```
  <input placeholder="Type Keyword here ....."  onChange={this.handleChange}   value={SearchResult} />
```

Comment: can you provide some more code

Comment: How does `item` look like and `filter` doesnot modify original array.

Comment: ok  i added @joy

Comment: can you provide details about what is the initial state of your component??i mean  what is the initial  values or its structure of this.state.all_items

Comment: the end point is bit complex first of all i have a object and then in this object i have numbers of Arrays then in arrays i have numbers of objects and in these object i have my values Item_name

Comment: the structure is like this :

`{
a: [{item_name: 'hello'},{item_name: 'humty'},{item_name: 'dumpty'},{item_name: 'world'}]
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, does it fix your issue?

```
this.state.all_items.filter(item => item.item_name.toLowerCase() === lowercasedFilter);
```

I've updated it slightly as you only need to check direct comparison rather than using indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to fix.

- check if `item_name` is not `null` before calling `toLowerCase()`
- `filter()` doesnot modify the original array so you need to store the result in a variable and then change the state.

Here is code

```
handleChange = event => { 
    const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase();
    let res = this.state.all_items.filter(item => {
      // console.log(item)
      return (item.item_name && item.item_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedFilter) !== -1)
    }); 
    this.setState({all_items:res, SearchResult: event.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi What is problem?

Comment: when i give an input in search field there is no change in my list . i give the example of my endpoint below your first comment

Answer (score 0):

as per the comments in other answer and in your question desciption i think you want to implement search suggetion component,which fetch list of item from api and on keypress of seach box filter the list of item based on user input.
to do it you will need to maintan two list of data one is provided by API and another one is filttered on user input so you component state should be like

```
  //a constructor of your component
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={
     //i assume all_items will be initialied at the componentDidmount event by api call
  all_items :
      [{item_name: 'hello'},{item_name: 'humty'},{item_name: 'dumpty'},{item_name: 'world'}] ,
  //use this to display suggestions by filtering  the all_items
   filtered_items:[],
  SearchResult:'',//you should name it searchQuery not SearchResult as it hold input from search box
  }

}
```

your event handle should be like this,if you check your code you are using searchResult from state before updating it

```
handleChange = event => { 
/***
 *  your old code ,which is wrong initially this.state.SearchResult will be ''
 * const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase(); 
 */
const lowercasedFilter = event.target.value;
//filter the all_items to make suggestion
let filtered_items =this.state.all_items.filter(item => {
return (item.item_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedFilter) !== -1)
 }); 
   if(filtered_items.length<=0){
  filtered_items=this.state.all_items;
  }
//now update both filtered items and searchResult,previosuly you are just filtering all items but not updating them
this.setState({ SearchResult:event.target.value,filtered_items:filtered_items });

   }
```

your code render suggetions

```
get_suggestion=()=>{
if(this.state.SearchResult.length>0){
  return <ul>
    {this.state.filtered_items.map((item)=>{
      return <li>{item.item_name}</li>
    })}
  </ul>
}
return null;
  }
```

your render method should be like this

```
  render() {
    let suggestions=this.get_suggestion();
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <input type='text' onKeyUp={this.handleChange} />
       {suggestions}
     </div>
   );
  }
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your time @joy but i implement your perception but the error remain same

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi check my answer now,i have tested it worked!